# Import pictures from twitter

Tags: php, twitter

Is possible to import pictures from twitter (not profile picture)using their API.I mean pictures attached in the tweets.

Help is highly appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would probably help you.

```
https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/USERNAME.xml?count=100&page=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Pictures aren't attached to tweets, but the URL to the images are. One thing that will make it easier is to use API calls that include entities. The URL entities are copies of the URL that are extracted from the tweet.  You can look at the file extension to figure out whether the URL is to an image.  Then write the code to read the image data from the URL.